# How can I change "AfterUrl" in an event receiver?

Tags: event-receivers

I have an event handler that changes the title of the file.  However shortly after this event handler ends SharePoint will open the editpage for the user to edit it. However `properties.AfterUrl` is still pointed at the original file name and is read-only.  Is there some clever way to make the edit page redirect to the new name once the event receiver finishes?

My event receiver code:

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb();
        bool allowUpdates = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates; //store original value
        this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
        try
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            var currItem = properties.ListItem;
            string fileName = printDate + username + printTime;
            currItem["Name"] = fileName;
            currItem["Title"] = fileName;

            currItem.Update();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writeLog(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUpdates; //restore original value
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting after an item is added might be tricky. If you would handle ItemAdding event then the only option that I know of to redirect from within an event receiver is to use `CancelWithRedirect`:

```
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
properties.RedirectUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/";
```

You need to keep in mind that in SharePoint 2013 `CancelWithRedirectUrl` is obsolete.

There is another approach which is more suitable for SharePoint 2013 - http://blog.sharepointalist.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-event-receiver-redirect.html

The form needs to be rendered in CSRRenderMode.ServerRender mode. Then you can use the following code snippet:

```
public class TestEventHandler : SPItemEventReceiver
 {
  private readonly HttpContext _currentContext;
  public TestEventHandler()
  {
   _currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
  }
  // Methods
  public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
  {
   var url = new StringBuilder("test.aspx");
   string urlRedirect = null;
   bool flag = SPUtility.DetermineRedirectUrl(url.ToString(), SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLayoutsPage, _currentContext, null, out urlRedirect);
   _currentContext.Response.Redirect(urlRedirect, true);
  }
 }
```

Keep in mind that you would still need to use `ItemAdding` instead of `ItemAdded`.